# Strange behaviour when in edit mode and a custom cell.editingAccessoryView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm using a UITableView for an application I'm building. When the UITableView goes to editing mode, the table cells display a textfield over the cell, as defined here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSString *cellLabel = [cellDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSString *cellData = [movieDictionary objectForKey:cellLabel];
  float x = cell.textLabel.frame.origin.x + 80;
  float y = cell.textLabel.frame.origin.y + 5;
  float w = cell.textLabel.frame.size.width - 80;
  float h = cell.textLabel.frame.size.height - 10;
  UITextField *editField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
  editField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", cellData];
  editField.tag = EDIT_FIELD_TAG;
  if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    editField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
  }
  editField.delegate = self;
  editField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
  cell.editingAccessoryView = editField;
}
```

Then, in the `setEditing` implementation:

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
  NSString *msg;
  if(!editing) {
    for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        UITextField *tf = [cell.subviews objectAtIndex:2];
        if(i==1) {
            if([tf.text intValue] == 0) {
                msg = @"The year you entered is not valid. Please enter a valid year.";
            }
        }
        if(!msg) {
            [movieDetails replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:tf.text];
            [movieDictionary setObject:tf.text forKey:[cellDetails objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }
    if(((NSString *)[movieDetails objectAtIndex:0]).length == 0) msg = @"The title you entered is not valid. Please enter a valid title.";
    if(((NSString *)[movieDetails objectAtIndex:1]).length == 0) msg = @"The year you entered is not valid. Please enter a valid year.";
    if(((NSString *)[movieDetails objectAtIndex:2]).length == 0) msg = @"The director you entered is not valid. Please enter a valid director.";
    if(((NSString *)[movieDetails objectAtIndex:3]).length == 0) msg = @"The cast you entered is not valid. Please enter a valid cast.";
    if(((NSString *)[movieDetails objectAtIndex:4]).length == 0) msg = @"The genre you entered is not valid. Please enter a valid genre.";
    if(!msg) {
        movie.movie_title = [movieDetails objectAtIndex:0];
        movie.movie_year = [[movieDetails objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
        movie.movie_director = [movieDetails objectAtIndex:2];
        movie.movie_cast = [movieDetails objectAtIndex:3];
        movie.movie_genre = [movieDetails objectAtIndex:4];
        [self.table reloadData];
        [self.table setEditing:editing animated: YES];
        [super setEditing:editing animated: YES];
        [self updateMovie];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"An error occurred!" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
  } else {
    [self.table setEditing:editing animated: YES];
    [super setEditing:editing animated: YES];
  }
}
```

Now, the strange thing happens when I enter edit mode for the second time consecutively. The first time, the editing style displays correctly, as seen here:

[image: Correct edit mode]

However, once I return from the editing mode and enter it again, the cells look like this:

[image: Faulty edit mode]

Has anyone encountered this before?

EDIT: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` implementation:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
  NSString *cellLabel = [cellDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSString *cellData = [movieDictionary objectForKey:cellLabel];
  cell.textLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@", cellLabel, cellData];
  cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be conforming to the table view data source *protocol* where are you are expected to return a `UITableViewCell` using:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acellForRowAtIndexPath%3a))

Not by creating custom accessory views.  Your best approach to the use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to return a different cell (one with a text field rather than a label) when the table is in editing mode.

Comment: I am implementing that method, the reason I'm creating the textfield in the willDisplayCell method is because the cellLabel frame isn't set in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Thanks for the answer though.